# How can I use django template variable as an argument to call javascript function?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, arguments

1.This is the html code where I am calling changeButton which is javascript function.

```
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#" onclick="changeButton( "{{ request.session.variable }}" );return false;">Button</a>
```

2. This is the javascript function which I am calling.

```
  function changeBookNowButton(variable) {
  document.getElementById("bookButton").innerHTML=variable
  }
```

3. value of the argument ::request.session.variable  is : joe

I am getting error: 
1. SyntaxError: syntax error if I pass argument in double quotes "{{ request.session.variable }}" 2. and If without qoutes {{ request.session.variable }} ReferenceError: joe is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#" onclick="changeButton( '{{ request.session.variable }}' );return false;">Button</a>
```

'{{ request.session.variable }}'